# Looking for a full (chain) source for a narration in tafsir al-Kashaf

Tags: hadith, tafseer, source-identification, reference-request

Imam [az-Zamakhshari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Zamakhshari) in his tafsir [al-Kashaf](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=204&surano=61&ayano=14) quoted a hadith (I've never heard before and couldn't find neither source nor full chain for) I also found quoted the same way in tafsir [al-Baydawi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Baydawi) (as far as I know this tafsir is like a commentary of al-Kashaf):

> عن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم: " من قرأ سورة الصف كان عيسى مصليا عليه مستغفرا له ما دام في الدنيا وهو يوم القيامة رفيقه ".

The hadith says (my own words and translation):

> Him who recites the surah as-Saff (61), 'Isa will send blessings to him and asking Allah for his forgivness (for the reciter) in this life and he will be his companion in the day of Judgment.

I'm looking for a full chain and an other full-source of this narration!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fabricated (*mawdū'*, Arabic: موضوع) hadith. Az-Zamakhshari quoted the hadith in his tafsīr without attribution, and so did Al-Baidāwi attributing it to Az-Zamakhshari. According to [*Takhrīj al-Ahādīth wa al-Athār*](http://waqfeya.com/book.php?bid=9221) (Arabic: تخريج الأحاديث والآثار الواقعة في تفسير الكشاف للزمخشري) by [Jamal ad-Dīn az-Zaila'i](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%AC%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%84_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B2%D9%8A%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%8A) (Arabic: جمال الدين أبو محمد عبد الله بن يوسف بن محمد الزيلعي) , in [Vol. 4, pp. 8](https://ia601400.us.archive.org/11/items/FP5121/04_5124.pdf), the chain of narration is:

1. The Prophet ﷺ
2. Ubai ibn Kā'b (Arabic: أبي بن كعب)
3. Zarr ibn Hubaish (Arabic: زر بن حبيش)
4. 'Atā' ibn Abu Maimūna (Arabic: عطاء بن أبي ميمونة) and 'Ali ibn Zaid (Arabic: علي بن زيد)
5. Makhad ibn 'Abdul-Wāhid (Arabic: مخلد بن عبد الواحد)
6. Shabāba ibn Siwār al-Fazāri (Arabic: شبابة بن سوار الفزاري)
7. 'Abdullah ibn Rūh al-Madāthini (Arabic: عبد الله بن روح المدائني)
8. Abu al-'Abbās Mohammad ibn Mūsa ar-Rāzi (Arabic: أبو العباس محمد بن موسى الرازي)
9. Ibn Hansh al-Muqri' (Arabic: ابن حنش المقرئ)
10. Abu al-Hussain al-Khabbāzi (Arabic: أبو الحسين الخبازي) — informed
11. Ath-Tha'lābi (Arabic: الثعلبي).

'Ali ibn Zaid (Arabic: علي بن زيد بن عبد الله بن زهير بن عبد الله بن جدعان) is weak in hadith. Abu Hātim ar-Rāzi, Abu Zar'a ar-Rāzi, Ad-Daraqutni, Adh-Dhahabi, Ahmad ibn Hanbal, Al-Bukhāri, Al-Hākim, Al-Qattān, Al-Wāqidi, An-Nasa'i, At-Tirmithi, Ibn Hajar al-'Asqalāni, Ibn Khozaima, Sufyan ibn 'Uūyayna, and Yahya ibn Ma'īn considered his hadiths forsaken for his weak memory, and for attributing to the Prophet ﷺ what was the companions (mawqūf, Arabic: موقوف). Ad-Dimashqi, Ibn Hibbān, and Ibn al-Qattān do not quote him for he used to narrate denounced (manakīr, Arabic: مناكير) hadiths, and was even called a liar.

Hadiths of Makhad ibn 'Abdul-Wāhid (Arabic: مخلد بن عبد الواحد) are also forsaken as he was a fabricator according to Adh-Dhahabi, Ibn Hibbān, and Abi Hātim ar-Rāzi.

Note that this is a partial validation of the people in the chain, stopping at Makhad ibn 'Abdul-Wāhid.

Comment: @Medi1Saif — I have updated the answer with the author's name,a link to the book, and a link to the specific verse. I have no knowledge of Az-Zamakhshari's involvement in the science of hadith, but all tafsīrs have weak (and lower) hadiths. See this [IslamWeb](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=119253) article (Arabic only).